# Mapping data to JQGrid with Ajax call

Tags: ajax, vb.net, jqgrid

I'm just trying to display a very simple JQGrid with data from an ajax call to a controller.  All I'm seeing is the grid headers, no data.  Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Here's the Ajax call and JQGrid setup..

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetLoanReport", "Report")',
            datatype: "json",
            height: "auto",
            colNames: ['Name', 'Random Stuff'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150, sortable: true },
              { name: 'RandomStuff', index: 'RandomStuff', width: 500, sortable: false }
            ],
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: true,
                root: 'rowdata',
                page: 'currpage',
                total: 'totalpages',
                records: 'totalrecords'
            },
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 30],
            rownumbers: false,
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: true,
            pager: "#page",
            caption: "Flat Data Example"
        });
```

Here's the controller code...

```
Function GetLoanReport() As JsonResult
    ViewData("Ribbon") = "partials/_statsRibbon"

    Dim response As New Response
    Dim model As New ReportModel

    model.Name = "Mark"
    model.RandomStuff = "Highfield"

    response.currpage = 1
    response.totalpages = 1
    response.totalrecords = 1
    response.rowdata = model


    Return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) 
End Function
```

Comment: Do you want to implement **server side paging** of data of you want to return all the data from `GetLoanReport` and jqGrid should make *local* paging, sorting and filtering/sorting the data? In any way the `rowdata` should be **array** of items (array of objects) instead of one **object** only with `Name` and `RandomStuff` properties. Sorry, I forgot the syntax of VB. Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: that was it.  How frustrating, haha.  I was setting the rowdata to an object rather than a list of objects.  When I changed it to a list of objects it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I'd like that I could help you. I posted the same information as the answer, which you can accept and "close" the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem: `rowdata` should be **array** of items (array of objects) instead of **one object** only with `Name` and `RandomStuff` properties.

Additionally you should decide whether you implement **server side** paging of data or you want to return *all the data* from `GetLoanReport` at once and jqGrid should make *local* paging, sorting and filtering/sorting the data? In the case you should use `loadonce: true` option. Additionally it's important to choose the fork of jqGrid, which you use: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7. I develop free jqGrid fork, which I can recommend you. If you use it, then I would recommend you to add `forceClientSorting: true` option additionally to `loadonce: true`. It will allows you to use `sortname` and `sortorder` options to sort the data returned from the server *before* it will be displayed.